# I need to recursively check a dynamic Tree Structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree-structure

I need your help. So the goal this time is that i want to recursively check my tree structure.

Basically this is what i need it to do:
[image]

On the on side i have a so called treeNode (example: 'Article.Artnr') and on the other a so called contextEntry (which has an 'Article').
I need to check if the name in treeNode exists in contextEntry, if it exists i need to check the type of it and than go on. Now the tricky Part: The next name in the namesSplit is 'Artnr' which i need to check if it is an property from 'Article' in the contextEntry. Again if it is i need to check it's type and go on. I don't know beforehand how deep my structure will be so i really would appreciate your help on this one.

```
let namesSplit = treeNode.name.split('.');

let key = namesSplit[0];

let contextEntry = exprData.contextEntry.find(_x => _x.name === key);
```

I have implemented my Recursive check like so:

```
function recursive(names, contextEntry) {
        for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (names[i] === contextEntry.name) {
                // getType(contextEntry.value);
                console.log('Name found in Context: ' + names[i]);
                continue;
            }
            if (names[i] == Object.keys(contextEntry.value)) {
                console.log(getType(contextEntry.value));
                console.log('Child Name found in Context: ' + names[i]);
                // console.log(Object.values(contextEntry.value));
            }
        }
    }
    recursive(namesSplit, contextEntry);
```

I also have to check the type of every value from the Context.
There are 4 possible datatypes: **Primitive**, **Array of Primitive**,
**Object**, **Array of Objects**

if the value in the context is either Primitive or an Array of Primitives it will throw an error, if it is an Object i need to just extract the value of it and if it is an Array of Objects i need to find the right object and than extract the value from it

VariableType is an enum.
My Check Function is implemented like so:

```
function getType(contextEntry.value) {
        if (Array.isArray(contextEntry.value)) {
            for (let i of contextEntry.value) {
                if (isPrimitive(i)) {
                    return VariableType.ARRAY_OF_PRIMITIVES;
                }
            }
            if (contextEntry.value.some(val => typeof val === 'object')) {
                return VariableType.ARRAY_OF_OBJECTS;
            }
        }
        if (typeof contextEntry.value === 'object' && contextEntry.value !== null) {
            return VariableType.OBJECT;
        }
        if (isPrimitive(contextEntry.value)) {
            return VariableType.PRIMITIVE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where are the values from? `context` vs `contextEntry`? what is `VariableType` (edited), what is the data you have and what should happen with it? and what does not work?

Comment: Sorry i just updated it, context and contextEntry are the same. VariableType is an enum which defines the 4 data types.

Comment: The tree structure and the recursive function logic needs to be able to distinguish between a leaf and a branch on the tree. If on a branch, the recursive function can keep going out to find the leaves on that branch or other branches. If on a leaf, there is no point to try and go out further from a leaf end point. The recursion logic will also need to know what has already been searched to avoid infinite loop conditions.

Comment: i updated my question, i hope it's a little clearer now

Comment: Some sample inputs and outputs would help.